# Targeting all images in a group in Actionscript with Flex Builder

Tags: image, apache-flex, actionscript

So I basically have this code:

```
<s:Group>
  <sImage source="assets/image1.gif"/>
  <sImage source="assets/image2.gif"/>
  <sImage source="assets/image3.gif"/>
  <sImage source="assets/image4.gif"/>
</s:Group>
```

Now I need to target each of them in actionscript to do a colorTransform on, how would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to get this working? Which part is the problem for you?

Comment: I suddenly came to the solution :) I was using getElementAt() and that only returns an Ivisualelement but I had to use getChildAt() which returns a displayobject so I could do my transform on it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Great stuff! Please add your solution as an answer to your question (yes, you're allowed to do that). That way, if ever anyone else has the same problem and googles and finds this page... they know how to solve it too :)

Comment: Probably better practice to cast the return from getElementAt() to DisplayObject.

Comment: Amy's right. You just got lucky that getChildAt() returned the correct instance; in other circumstances it wouldn't.